# Error when deploying Strongloop/Loopback using MySQL datasource to Openshift

Tags: mysql, openshift, loopbackjs, strongloop

I've been trying to deploy a Strongloop/Loopback using MySQL datasource application to Openshift without success. Below are the steps I followed.

1. Installed Node on my Windows 7.
2. Did a npm install -g strongloop
3. Created a datasourcefollowing the instructions from this [link](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-rest-api-openshift-redhat/)
4. Instead of MongoDB I used MySQL. Below are my setups.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "loopback-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "server/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "slc run",
    "pretest": "jshint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "compression": "^1.0.3",
    "errorhandler": "^1.1.1",
    "loopback": "^2.0.0",
    "loopback-boot": "^2.0.0",
    "loopback-connector-mysql": "^2.1.1",
    "loopback-datasource-juggler": "^2.0.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "loopback-explorer": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

datasources.json

```
{
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "memory"
  },
  "mysql": {
    "host": "mysql-openshift-db-host",
    "port": mysql-openshift-db-port,
    "database": "gearname",
    "password": "mysql-password",
    "name": "mysql",
    "connector": "mysql",
    "user": "mysql-username"
  }
}
```

model-config.json

```
{
  "_meta": {
    "sources": [
      "../common/models",
      "./models"
    ]
  },
  "User": {
    "dataSource": "db"
  },
  "AccessToken": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "ACL": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "RoleMapping": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "Role": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "Demo": {
    "dataSource": "mysql",
    "public": true
  }
}
```

It works when running it locally on my machine. However, I get the following error when deploying it to Openshift and then going to the http:///explorer and trying out one of the methods for my model.

```
==> strongloop/logs/node.log <==
2015-07-12T14:08:02.538Z pid:27006 worker:supervisor INFO strong-agent not profiling, configuration not found.
2015-07-12T14:08:02.543Z pid:27006 worker:supervisor Generate configuration with:
2015-07-12T14:08:02.545Z pid:27006 worker:supervisor     npm install -g strong-cli
2015-07-12T14:08:02.545Z pid:27006 worker:supervisor     slc strongops
2015-07-12T14:08:02.546Z pid:27006 worker:supervisor See http://docs.strongloop.com/strong-agent for more information.
Browse your REST API at http://localhost:3000/explorer
Web server listening at: http://localhost:3000/

assert.js:92
  throw new assert.AssertionError({
        ^
AssertionError: options must be an object
    at MySQL.SQLConnector.execute (/var/lib/openshift/55a23e52e0b8cdb70700003f/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/loopback-connector-mysql/node_module
s/loopback-connector/lib/sql.js:391:3)
    at MySQL.find [as all] (/var/lib/openshift/55a23e52e0b8cdb70700003f/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/loopback-connector-mysql/node_modules/loopb
ack-connector/lib/sql.js:1051:8)
    at Function.find (/var/lib/openshift/55a23e52e0b8cdb70700003f/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/dao.js:736:34)
    at SharedMethod.invoke (/var/lib/openshift/55a23e52e0b8cdb70700003f/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/s
hared-method.js:207:17)
    at HttpContext.invoke (/var/lib/openshift/55a23e52e0b8cdb70700003f/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/ht
tp-context.js:243:12)
    at /var/lib/openshift/55a23e52e0b8cdb70700003f/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/remote-objects.js:475:
9
    at execStack (/var/lib/openshift/55a23e52e0b8cdb70700003f/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/remote-obje
cts.js:346:7)
    at /var/lib/openshift/55a23e52e0b8cdb70700003f/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/loopback/lib/application.js:329:13
    at /var/lib/openshift/55a23e52e0b8cdb70700003f/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/loopback/lib/models/model.js:267:5
    at /var/lib/openshift/55a23e52e0b8cdb70700003f/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/loopback/lib/models/acl.js:443:19

npm info loopback-app@0.0.0 Failed to exec start script
npm ERR! loopback-app@0.0.0 start: `slc run`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the loopback-app@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the loopback-app package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     slc run
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls loopback-app
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! command "/var/lib/openshift/55a23e52e0b8cdb70700003f/strongloop//bin/node/node" "/var/lib/openshift/55a23e52e0b8cdb70700003f/strongloop/bin/n
ode/npm" "start" "-d"
npm ERR! cwd /var/lib/openshift/55a23e52e0b8cdb70700003f/app-root/runtime/repo
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.30
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/lib/openshift/55a23e52e0b8cdb70700003f/app-root/runtime/repo/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

==> app-root/logs/haproxy.log <==
[WARNING] 192/100828 (395134) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer4 connection problem, info: "Connection refused", check duration: 0ms.
 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 192/100828 (395134) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you clean up node_modules and make sure latest deps are installed?

Answer (score 1):

Your application needs to listen on your openshift ip address & port, it seems that it is still trying to listen on localhost:3000 in the code, you should also make sure that you are connecting to mysql using the mysql environment variables.  Below are a couple of resources that you should read through:

https://developers.openshift.com/en/node-js-overview.html
https://developers.openshift.com/en/databases-mysql.html

Comment: I modified my config.json file and changed the host and port and used "mycloud-mydomain.rhcloud.com" and port 80. As for the mysql settings, I believe I have this correctly setup as I'm using those from the env in openshift. However, it is still throwing the same error. Also added that I installed Strongloop in Openshift using the Strongloop cartridge [here](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-rest-api-openshift-redhat/). I dont seem to have some NODE variables defined. Not sure if this is relevant.

Comment: You should be using port 8080, and the openshift ip address (OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP), not your cname

Comment: I dont seem to have the env OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP. I created the application using the Strongloop [cartridge](https://github.com/strongloop/openshift-cartridge-strongloop). Somehow the NODE related variables where not set. Also, just to point out, I am able to open the http://mycloud-mydomain.rhcloud.com/explorer and I can see the user and the demo that I created. Only when I click one of the methods of my custom model will I then get the error.